# Listen all messages for an exist socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, proxy, listen

I have a desktop software in my Linux that have a socket in port 9000. They connect with another application.
I need to see all messages sent for another application. How can I do to make a socket proxy to log all messages passed?

Nowadays I have:

Software1 create a socket in port 9000.
Software2 make a connection with port 9000.

I want:
Software1 create a socket in port 9000.
My new application create a socket in port 9005.
Software2 make a connection with port 9005.
All messages sent for My new application should log and pass a message for another software.

How can I make this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these plain TCP sockets? webSockets?  What is the protocol on the socket?

Comment: Websockets is the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to take all incoming webSocket messages arriving on port 9000 and send them out on port 9000 (forwarding them), then you can do that like this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// create webSocket server for incoming connections on port 9000
const wServer = new WebSocket.Server({port: 9000});

const wClient = new WebSocket('ws://www.somehost.com', {});

wClient.on('open', () => {
    console.log("connected to other client");
});

wClient.on('error, err => {
    console.log("client error", err);
});

// server event handlers
wServer.on('listening', () => {
    console.log("server started");
});

wServer.on('connection', ws => {
    // forward all incoming messages to the other server
    ws.on('message', msg => {
        wClient.send(msg);
    });
});

wSserver.on('error', err => {
    console.log("server error", err);
});
```

Comment: @RenatoCaddino - Did this answer your question?